# Area of a triangle with its sides in arithmetic progression.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

The sides of a triangle are $a, b$ and $c$ and the opposite internal angles are $A$, $B$ and $C$ respectively, to each of these sides. It is known that $a, b, c$, in this order, form an arithmetic progression. If the perimeter of the triangle measures $15$ and 
$$\frac{\cos A}{a}+\frac{\cos B}{b}+\frac{\cos C}{c}=\frac{77}{240}$$
 What is the area of the triangle?

I know that $\dfrac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{2abc}=\dfrac{77}{240}$, by the cosine law, and $b=5.$ How do I proceed from here?

Answer (score 2):

If $b=5$, that means $a+c=10\Rightarrow a^2+c^2=100-2ac$ and thus:

$$\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{2abc}=\frac{77}{240} \Rightarrow \frac{125-2ac}{10ac}=\frac{77}{240}\Rightarrow ac=24$$

So $a+c=10$ and $ac=24$. Can you end it from here? (Recall Heron's formula for the area).

Comment: Yeah. Thank you!

Comment: a+c=10 and a²+c²=52. This can be a=4 and c=6. 4+1=5; 5+1=6. Then, the area will be (5.6.senA)/2. By cosine law and making sen²=1-cos², the area is equal to (15√7)/4.

Comment: @thiagodurso, yes, that's good. Or you can see that the semiperimeter is $s=\frac{15}{2}$ and use Heron's formula for the area $\sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}$

Answer (score 1):

Continue with

$$\dfrac{77}{240}=\dfrac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{2abc}=\dfrac{b^2+(a+c)^2-2ac}{2abc}
=\frac{5^2+10^2-2ac}{10ac}$$

to get $ac = 24$. Then, calculate,

$$\cos B = \frac{a^2+c^2-b^2}{2ac}=\frac{(a+c)^2-2ac-b^2}{2ac}=\frac{10^2-48-5^2}{48}=\frac9{16}$$

Thus, the area is

$$A = \frac12 ac\sin B = \frac12 ac\sqrt{1-\cos^2B} 
=\frac12\cdot24\cdot\sqrt{1-\frac{81}{256}} =\frac{15\sqrt7}4$$